# Table formatting equal to page size

Tags: tables

I have been looking around on this forum, but unfortunately I couldn't find the answer to my question. As given below, I make use of a table. The table contains two columns and I want the first column to be wider, without the table being centred at the middle of the page. I want the table to start at the left hand side of the page.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{longtable}

\title{Equations in chapters}

\author{Student NL}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\textbf{Given information}
\begin{longtable}{l p{12cm}}

Demand Mediamarkt Essen (ME) & 35 per day\\
Demand Mediamarkt Neuss (MN) & 20 per day\\
Demand Mediamarkt Aachen (MA) & 42 per day\\
\\
Cost each trip ME & 1,100 \\
Cost each trip MN & 1,300 \\
Cost each trip MA & 1,500 \\
\\
Purchase price per cooker & 78 \\
Number of days in year & 365 \\
Holding cost rate for each store & 20 percent per year \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

How would I be able to do this?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution,  2 tables with some difference.
you need to set `\firstcol` the width of first col the second will be computed by pdftex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcommand*{\firstcol}{10cm}
\newcommand*{\secondcol}{\dimexpr\textwidth-\firstcol-4\tabcolsep\relax}

\title{Equations in chapters}
\author{Student NL}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\textbf{Given information}\\


\begin{longtable}{p{\firstcol}p{\secondcol}}
\hline
Demand Mediamarkt Essen (ME) & 35 per day\\
Demand Mediamarkt Neuss (MN) & 20 per day\\
Demand Mediamarkt Aachen (MA) & 42 per day\\
\\
Cost each trip ME & 1,100 \\
Cost each trip MN & 1,300 \\
Cost each trip MA & 1,500 \\
\\
Purchase price per cooker & 78 \\
Number of days in year & 365 \\
Holding cost rate for each store & 20 percent per year \\
\end{longtable}


%\renewcommand*{\firstcol}{10cm}
\renewcommand*{\secondcol}{\dimexpr\textwidth-\firstcol-2\tabcolsep\relax}
\begin{longtable}{@{}p{\firstcol}p{\secondcol}@{}}
\hline
Demand Mediamarkt Essen (ME) & 35 per day\\
Demand Mediamarkt Neuss (MN) & 20 per day\\
Demand Mediamarkt Aachen (MA) & 42 per day\\
\\
Cost each trip ME & 1,100 \\
Cost each trip MN & 1,300 \\
Cost each trip MA & 1,500 \\
\\
Purchase price per cooker & 78 \\
Number of days in year & 365 \\
Holding cost rate for each store & 20 percent per year \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want the [long]table to start at the left hand [edge] of the [text block].

You need to (a) modify the values of the length parameters `\LTleft` and `\LTright` and (b) make sure that there's no whitespace to the left of the left-most column. These requirements are met in the following MWE (minimum working example):

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{longtable}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}  % no padding on the left
\setlength\LTright\fill % "infinite padding on the right

\begin{document}

\hrule % Just to illustrate the width of the textblock

\begin{longtable}{@{} l p{12cm} }  % <- note the "@{}" particle

Demand Mediamarkt Essen (ME) & 35 per day\\
Demand Mediamarkt Neuss (MN) & 20 per day\\
Demand Mediamarkt Aachen (MA) & 42 per day\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```